# The process of deploying a web application to URL

Tags: java, hosting, war, server

I have developed my first web application in Java (Spring, Struts2, Jetty server). I am a trainee Developer and I would like some clarification on what do I need to do to get my app running on URL.

My project is saved as a .WAR file. What would be my next step to get my app working? Assume I have a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy it on web server like tomcat/jetty etc and start your server..

Follow [this doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/index.html) if you are planning to use tomcat for further details.

Comment: I am deploying it on a localhost, what should I do to deploy it to my domain? Thank you for your reply